# [] is not a valid type

Tags: mulesoft, raml, anypoint-platform

```
`#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: []
properties
  assignedTail:
     description: Tail Number (A/C)
     example: 220 NV
     type: string`
```

While I am writing RAML for 1.0 I am getting the error in RAML for Array earlier it was fine but since today we are getting issues. Is it possible there have been any change in raml declaration of RAML.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type for the elements of the array is missing.

Example for an array of strons:

```
type: string[]
```

Comment: Sorry we have already declared properties inside our feature although we found the answer we must put items: array above the properties and the error will disappear and coordinate with example. Thanks for the help